# Trying To understand Set State of React - Set State and apply it on single component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

**NOTE: Its App.js component**

I have a State

```
state = {

  contacts: [...data is coming from an api],
  bgColors: ["bg-red","bg-blue",...so On]

  // bg colors array consist of class coming from css

}
```

inside render function->

I Used `this.state.contacts.map` to display data from contacts(state)

inside map function there is a div with className

```
<div className={`col-sm-3 relative book  ${Here I want to display bgColors String one by one} `}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the native `Array.join` method to generate a string of classes:

```
<div className={`col-sm-3 relative book ${this.state.bgColors.join(' ')} `} />
```

Comment: Seems like My question is not clear I will upload my code after 6 hrs because right now I am in office............

but

<div className={`col-sm-3 relative book  ${Here I want to display bgColors String one by one} `}>

is Inside 

map function and its alreacy giving me result 

<div className={`col-sm-3 relative book  bg-red,bg-blue,bgpink......so on`}>

just by this / without join function

<div className={`col-sm-3 relative book ${this.state.bgColors} `} />

Comment: @pDotJoe Yes, I have a feeling you will have to potentially post a more complete example. I am presuming you have that div in a different component now that I think about it, so you will have to pass state down and that's where your issue might be. But we need fuller code, including the host and child component to help you further :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-csg3wt?embed=1&file=App.js


please check the code

Comment: @pDotJoe I am unsure what you are asking here, but from a quick glance your `addClass` method does not do what you think it does, it will always just return the first element in the array. Otherwise it looks fine, so add it to your question and refine your question to get more accurate answers...